# SQLAlchemy/Postgres: Intermittent Error Serializing Object After Commit

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a Flask application that uses SQLAlchemy (with some Marshmallow for serialization and deserialization).

I'm currently encountering some intermittent issues when trying to dump an object post-commit.

To give an example, let's say I have implemented a (multi-tenant) system for tracking system faults of some sort. This information is contained in a `fault` table:

```
class Fault(Base):
    __tablename__ = "fault"

    fault_id = Column(BIGINT, primary_key=True)
    workspace_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('workspace.workspace_id'))
    local_fault_id = Column(Integer)
    name = Column(String)
    description = Column(String)
```

I've removed a number of columns in the interest of simplicity, but this is the core of the model. The columns should be largely self explanatory, with `workspace_id` effectively representing tenant, and `local_fault_id` representing a tenant-specific fault sequence number, which is handled via a separate `fault_sequence` table.

This `fault_sequence` table holds a counter against workspace, and is updated by means of a simple `on_fault_created()` function that is executed by a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER fault_created
  AFTER INSERT
  ON "fault"
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE on_fault_created();
```

**So - the problem**:
I have a Flask endpoint for fault creation, where we create an instance of a `Fault` entity, add this via a scoped session (`session.add(fault)`), then call `session.commit()`.

It seems that this is always successful in creating the desired entities in the database, executing the sequence update trigger etc. However, when I then try to interrogate the `fault` object for updated fields (after `commit()`), around 10% of the time I find that each key/field just points to an Exception:

> psycopg2.errors.InFailedSqlTransaction: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

Which seems to boil down to the following:

```
(psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation) invalid input syntax for integer: ""
[SQL: SELECT fault.fault_id AS fault_fault_id, fault.workspace_id AS fault_workspace_id, fault.local_fault_id AS fault_local_fault_id, fault.name as fault_name, fault.description as fault_description
FROM fault 
WHERE fault.fault_id = %(param_1)s]
[parameters: {'param_1': 166}]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/2j8
```

**My question, then**, is what do we think could be causing this?

I *think* it smells like a race condition, with the update trigger not being complete before SQLAlchemy has tried to get the updated data; perhaps `local_fault_id` is null, and this is resulting in the `invalid input syntax` error.

That said, I have very low confidence on this. Any guidance here would be amazing, as I could really do with retrieving that sequence number that's incremented/handled by the update trigger.

Thanks

---

Edit 1:

Some more info:

- I have tried removing the update trigger, in the hope of eliminating that as a suspect. This behaviour is still intermittently evident, so I don't think it's related to that.
- I have tried adopting usage of `flush` and `refresh` before the commit, and this allows me to get the values that I need - though commit still appears to 'break' the `fault` object.

---

Edit 2:
So it really seems to be more postgres than anything else. When I interrogate my database logs, this is the weirdest thing. I can copy and paste the command it says is failing, and I struggle to see how this integer value in the `WHERE` clause is possibly evaluating to an empty string.

This same error is reproducible with `SELECT ... FROM fault WHERE fault.fault_id = ''`, which in no way seems to be the query making to the DB.

I am stumped.

[image: logs]

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence "This same error is reproducible with SELECT ... FROM fault WHERE fault.fault_id = '', which in no way seems to be the query making to the DB." seems to indicate that you are trying to access an object that does not have the database primary key "fault_id".

I guess, given that you did not provide the code, that you are adding the object to your session (session.add), committing (session.commit) and then using the object.  As fault_id is autogenerated by the database, the fault object in the session (in memory) does not have fault_id.

I believe you can correct this with:

```
session.add(fault)
session.commit()
session.refresh(fault)
```

The refresh needs to be AFTER commit to refresh the fault object and retrieve fault_id.

If you are using async, you need

```
session.add(fault)
await session.commit()
await session.refresh(fault)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, in the scenario where the dump doesn't work (as in, we are unable to retrieve the autogenerated IDs, trigger-inserted values etc. post-commit), refresh will also fail and throw an exception! 

With simpler cases, the `commit()` call seems to successfully expire the object, and it is then automatically refreshed on interrogation of a given field. 

:(

Comment: I would say, additionally, the log outputs show what postgres is actually doing, but all of these queries originate from SQLAlchemy - but your order of operations is correct, i.e. add, commit, access.

Comment: It seems that you have three tables linked in away that two of them have to update simultaneously.  workspace_id links to both fault and fault_sequence, when a fault is created, fault_sequence needs to "simultaneously" be updated or another fault could use the same sequence number. Perhaps you could increment the fault_sequence table and reserving the "id" before updating the fault table.

Comment: Another approach could be to replace the fault_sequence table by a table property of workspace. The property would calculate the number of links to fault. (long shot here as I do not know the reason for the third table).

Comment: The sequence table (third table) really just exists to allow sequentially increasing workspace-specific fault numbers, and I believe that's a relatively common pattern in this kind of scenario.

What really (really, really) confuses me is why postgres has an issue with `SELECT ... FROM fault WHERE fault.fault_id = 406`.

If that were to be a `fault_id` that doesn't exist, I should just get nothing back - and 406 is clearly an integer and not an empty string.

Comment: I believe the syntax is SELECT ... FROM fault WHERE fault_id = 406